# How do you parse "hair do"

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

Is "do" understood as a noun or verb in "hair do"?

Asking this in search of "to make do".

Bonus points if it can be related to German *Tolle* "tuft [of hair], that thing that Elvis had on his head", itself of obscure origin, surely under influence of *toll* "wild, great, fun".

En. *dole* doesn't seem to be a bad fit, either, as general as its cognates are (portion, piece, divide).

Comment: The phrase comes from the idiom _do one's hair_, which means to wash, brush, cut, and/or style (women's) hair_, often in a particular fashion. Any of these variations came to be called a "hairdo" (aka _hair-do_ and _hair do_). So the ultimate source of the _do_ is `ACT` _do_ from _do your hair_.  I wouldn't parse _do_ here at all; it's just the last syllable of the noun _hairdo_.

Comment: Consider "do" to be a noun, in this sense.  There are a few other contexts where "do" is a noun, as in "We're having a do (party) for Sandra."

Comment: _Make do_ is unrelated; it means to _make_ the resources you have _do_ (be sufficient) for the task in hand.

Comment: not sure if it's related to either of those words. but maybe =)

Comment: What do you mean when you write *Asking this in search of "to make do"*?  Do you mean that you're asking this to see if it's related to "to make do"?  If so, then no -- as explained in the answers, it comes from *how you **do** your hair*.  Analogy: *In Detroit they make cars; this year they've come out with a new make of car.*

Comment: @aparente001 I don't remember what my exact thoughts were. The motivation with regards to "make do" is to understand all the possible parses, why some people hear "make due" and why others find that "distressing". The corresponding question hasn't been asked yet, only preliminaries. When *do* may be deemed an uninflected result noun like *make, run, cut, ...*, the usual (unconvincing or at least not substantiated) explanation by contraction from "make it do" needs to be called into question.

Comment: Thanx for your explanation. Anyway, I know what *hair-do* means, but I was asking for a syntax analysis and its derivation, which for a single word is a bit silly.

Comment: @vectory - I recommend that you use simpler sentences, *complete* sentences, to express yourself, because sometimes the text you write is hard to understand.  People here go to an effort to help others.  Please, help us help you.

Comment: @aparente The request for a syntax analysis for a single word was a bit silly. Responding with anything else than a syntactic analysis of the word is likewise silly. Is that better?

Comment: @vectory - I meant, in general.  My spouse is German.  Our common language is English.  We've found that we have fewer misunderstandings if we avoid the common shortcuts one might be able to make in conversations with other native speakers.  I think that if you make a point of using full sentences, and avoiding long, complex sentences, I (at least) will understand you better.

Comment: Particle board = particle-board = particleboard. The open, hyphenated, and closed forms of a **single lexeme**, the compound noun _particleboard_. Hair-do / hairdo is likewise a single lexeme, a compound noun. This is almost like asking 'What part of speech is _do_ in _weirdo_?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, your first line is nonsense, if (and only if) the noun *do* has formed from exactly the kind of compound word I am asking about (*hairdo*, *weirdo*?> *do*). "*This is almost like asking 'What part of speech is do in weirdo*". Yes, this is *Etymology*? Albeit, that word seems to have become a "single lexeme" meaning approximately *trivia, fun facts about words with count count*. I' m short of calling it history revisionism by now. Damn Grammar Nazis (by law of Godwin, the discussion is over).

Comment: 'I wouldn't parse _do_ here at all; it's just the last syllable of the noun _hairdo_. ' I was merely paraphrasing Professor Lawler and adding further explanation. In case other enquirers here are confused by the question. No matter _what_ the etymology, 'hairdo' or its spelling variants is just a single lexeme, a compound noun, now. You ask 'How do you parse _hair do_ [/hairdo]?' This question should be closed; it lacks research and as it stands is predicated on a lack of understanding of basic concepts

Comment: @EdwinAshworth please don't answer in comments and don't propagate national grammar socialism. Fundamentally, this concept of which the question lacks is the concept "hair-do". It presupposes a basic understanding of the meaning that is part of the core vocabulary and thus prerequisite to participating in ELU. It expects an understanding of syntax and the more intricate parts of grammar that go into forming this noun phrase. The noun-phrase is lexical, but it is not monomorphemic. So I was asking how the "single lexeme" has to be parsed to be recognized as such. Feel free to add your answer.

Comment: Your question is akin to "How do you parse 'radiator'?" You can't parse single words. And I explain why I close-vote what I consider to be inappropriate questions. In 'comments'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: This is not the same. The striking difference is that hair-do is rather of English stock, while radiator is recognizably not. Ironically, an advanced speaker can tell from the suffix \*-tor that it is from Latin, if the vowel-sequence /iˌeɪ/ was not telling enough. I have to admit that *parsing* and *syntax* are a poor choice of terminology on my part. After all, I have not filed this under *syntax*. It is difficult to talk about etymology from a synchronic view, but it is no etymologic fallacy to presume that native speakers imagine possible origins to form a conviction ...

Comment: ... the only fallacy then is that they would always have to be correct. They don't have to. If they try in many cases they are simply mistaken. So the conviction can remain undecided, nearly unimportant as you try to imply. I reason from the point of view that it maybe important. Your insistance that, no, it has to be ignored in turn is but your own personal opinion overruled by the answers in here, all of which I try to appreciate, especially yours, as I am trying to argue that *make due/do* is a "single lexeme" too, at which point you will very suddenly disagree in an instance. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hair-do (or hairdo) is a hairstyle. You have your hair done by a stylist and the result is a hair-do. In this case "do" is a noun.

> A hairstyle, **hairdo**, or haircut refers to the styling of hair,
>   usually on the human scalp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairstyle

---

"do" on its own can be a noun - 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do

Answer (score 1):

It is the way your hair is *done*; the way you do your hair (or others, such as hairdressers, barbers, stylists *do* your hair). Your hair do. (It acts as a noun phrase.)

I would venture that this ambiguous application of **[do](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do)** is related to the word's catch-all etymology, including "make," "do," or "place."

> Middle English don, from Old English dōn; akin to Old High German tuon to do, Latin -dere to put, facere to make, do, Greek tithenai to place, set

Or it could refer to some goo used to style hair like 'Hair Doo' or 'Kleenex.' Who the hell knows

Comment: The product *Hair Doo* came *after* the *hair-do*.

Answer (score 0):

Do is a noun from the verb "to do":

Hair do = noun + noun, thus "hair do" = A **do** associated with hair.

The noun and verb "do" are usually only understandable from the context but, broadly they represent some sort of action.

Compare,

"I'm going to have my hair **done** tomorrow."

"She **did** her hair in a ponytail"

"Her usual hair-**do** is a ponytail."

Thus "do" is a utility word that, in this context, is equivalent to "to arrange/style" or "an arrangement/a style".

The following are some examples from OED to give the idea:

> **Do** (n.) **1. a. The action of doing, or that which is done; action, business.**
>
> 1988   J. Cartwright Interior viii. 90   **Dreadful gas-bag... All talk and no do.**
>
> **1. b. Originally English regional and nonstandard. A social event, a party; a performance or show.**
>
> 1999   M. Syal Life isn't All Ha Ha Hee Hee (2000) ii. 60   *Red Box are having a do upstairs... You ought to call in.*
>
> **1.c. Originally English regional (northern). With modifying word. An affair, occurrence, experience, or situation (of the kind specified).**
>
> 1992   G. M. Fraser Quartered Safe out Here 160   *I was startled to hear Grandarse..say in a grim harsh voice: ‘It's a bad do. By Christ, it's a bad do!’*

Comment: I'd argue that *all* can be a pronoun and the arguments can be parsed as verbs. "everybody talks, nobody does". I'm aware of the adverbial use of *all*, as much as *no* can hardly be parsed as pronoun (instead of *none*, e.g.), but comparing *no wiser, none the wiser* it may be *all... no do*. Admittedly, this do no sense make in modern diction, but it would be faithful to the origin of *not*. Since the whole thing is a set phrase or a so called snow-clone, possibly inhereted, I cannot accept you (or the OED) resting purely on synchronic evidence.

Comment: For reference, [credo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credo) reflects \*-d^(h)eH- "do, set, place". That would be literally *make-believe*, haha. The ending should have erroded further in inherited English lexical stock though, I'm sure, but sometimes these things become reinstated by analogy (to a noun, in view of your answer, but I remain unconvinced). I didn't know that when I asked the question.